# cron mysqldump saying not using password

Tags: php, cron, mysql

I am trying to run a `mysqldump` using a `cron` job. I get the following error:

```
Enter password: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'user_name'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
```

Here is the line of code trying to connect:

`$command = "mysqldump --opt -h ".$dbhost." -u ".$dbuser." -p ".$dbpass." ".$dbname." | gzip > ".$backup_file;
system($command);`

Why is it saying (using password: NO)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be any space between the `-p` and your `password`.

For example, this is correct:

```
-pPASSWORD
```

This is wrong

```
-p PASSWORD
```

And you are doing:

```
-p ".$dbpass."
  ^ space here
```